# Why aren't variables being recognized even when i properly set them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am relatively new to Xcode and Swift and i was following this guide: https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#app but three of the variables aren't being recognized even though they were properly recognized earlier:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: InputModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.Street

        return myCell
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Set selected location to var
    selectedLocation = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
    // Manually call segue to detail view controller
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    let detailVC  = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    // Set the property to the selected location so when the view for
    // detail view controller loads, it can access that property to get the feeditem obj
    detailVC.selectedLocation = selectedLocation
}
```

the result i got back was "use of unresolved identifier selectedLocation" twice and "use of unresolved identifier feedItems". i should also say that i changed the title of locationModel() to InputModel, and address to street. i can explain more and add source files if need be.

Edit: sorry, the variables were set earlier, here:

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocol  {

        //Properties
        var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
        var selectedLocation : InputModel = InputModel()
        @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //set delegates and initialize homeModel

            self.listTableView.delegate = self
            self.listTableView.dataSource = self

            let homeModel = HomeModel()
            homeModel.delegate = self
            homeModel.downloadItems()

        }

        func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

            feedItems = items
            self.listTableView.reloadData()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // Return the number of feed items
            return feedItems.count

        }
```

Comment: Show where have you initialized variables?

Comment: And please, show the *specific* lines in error?

Comment: Look at arturdev's answer. The clue is the level of indentation of those second two functions. If they were in the class they wouldn't be all the way against the left. The extra curly brace that arturdev pointed out is closing the class, and its scope, making those properties out of scope. You can double click on any brace and Xcode will select all of the text from that brace to its counterpart. Anything that is outside the highlighted area can not access any variables declared inside the highlighted area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the culprit is the extra closing bracket "}".

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: InputModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.Street

        return myCell
    }

}  <================ Delete this bracket because it is redundant here and move to the end  ======

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ....
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
            return feedItems.count

    }
} <======== MOVE IT HERE
```

Comment: Given that Jordan didn't mention having an error about an extra closing bracket he likely needs to _move_ the bracket to the end of the class rather than delete it. Xcode would be able to help him out if he just deletes the bracket though (it's good at finding unmatched brackets, but not poorly positioned ones).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're missing the declaration of two variables "selectedLocation" and "feedItems"

That, from the code you posted are in this lines

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Missing the declaration of both variables here
    selectedLocation = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
    // The rest of the code
}
```

And missing only one variable here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // previous code ...
        // Missing variable declaration in the next line
        let item: InputModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
        // rest of the code
    }
}
```

Not knowing where and how they were declared it's hard to know where the error is.

First of all, are these variables inside the same class that these functions?

If not that's the problem, you'll need to get the instance of the class where they're set for example

```
otherclass.selectedLocation = otherclass.feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
```

If they are, try to access them using the self declaration (it shouldn't be necessary but it might work) for example

```
self.selectedLocation = self.feedItems[indexPath.row] as! InputModel
```

Would be easier if you could provide the code where these variables are set though

Comment: so i used the self declaration and it brought up a new error: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'selectedLocation' twice.